# I want to increase the speed of my 12v DC trolling motor

Tags: circuit-design, dc, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor

This has been a project I have wanted to do for some time now. I live on a large lake  where gas engines are not allowed. I love to fish, but some of the best spots are a long boat ride from home going only 5 miles per hour. What would be the safest and more reliable way to increase the speed of the motor using the existing components?

the "MINI KOTA endura 44" is the only "EXTRA" motor I'm willing to experiment with.
I don't know if it might help answer some of the questions, but I found the manual online:

https://minnkotamotors.johnsonoutdoors.com/sites/johnsonoutdoors-store/files/assets/misc/MI/M/MIN_productmanual_EnduraC2-45/MIN_productmanual_EnduraC2-45.pdf?_ga=2.248790979.515972356.1601483274-397649940.1601483274.

I have started learning about voltage multiplier circuits, maybe increasing the diameter of the wire windings?

I would appreciate some input because this has been drilling a hole in my brain!

Comment: Your not going to get dramatic improvements in speed with anything simple you can do at home.  Page 10 of the product manual you linked to shows how much current and voltage larger trolling motors take.  Rebuilding an electric motor to take the higher voltage and current is not trivial, and may be physically not possible (not enough space in the housing and rotor for the different winding.)  Getting it water tight afterwards would be fun, too.

Comment: You need a 24 volt battery system with a much higher capacity and a much larger motor.

Comment: Two bolts and the petrol head comes off an old abandoned Seagull 2-stroke outboard. Consider mounting a big fat BLDC motor in its place instead of rewinding those trolling motors.

Comment: The *safest* way to increase the speed of the boat is to duplicate the propulsion system, i.e. add another battery, trolling motor, and whatever else goes with it. That way, you get a higher speed and you still get home if one goes wrong. If the extra weight sinks it before you leave the jetty, it is not far to swim to the bank and devise a different strategy.

Comment: (Off-topic) [Torqeedo](https://www.torqeedo.com/en) expensive, but fun.

Comment: Have you looked at changing the propeller to a faster one (higher pitch)? How long is your boat (i.e. to determine your hull speed)?

Comment: Use two trolling motors. Done. That said, be mindful of the reasons there are no motors allowed on the lake. One is of course noise and pollution that come with running outboards. The other is likely to limit the speed, and thus, the wake your boat will make. Will your faster setup run afoul of that?

Comment: @MattJames, don't get me wrong, but, your problems are gone: if there is no solution, you don't need to worry with the problem of building this device. :-) Trust us: this is not a feasible project. Even a person that has the knowledge and skills for building such a thing without asking for help would not try to do it, because such a person would know that a commercial product will be cheaper - and best - than anything a DIYer could project and build himself. Keep the trolling motor, and good fishing! I really envy (for the good side) a person that lives by a lake where he can go fishing. ;-)

Comment: Rewinding the motor for a different power is a total non-starter. Giving it a higher voltage and improving the cooling may be more feasible, but simply duplicating the system is far and away the most practical. You get a bit more speed, or twice the range at the same speed, and dual system redundancy into the bargain.

Comment: The first version saw me jam 4 relays into the Striker trolling motor top-box to give me some forward controls but it was a lot of heat plummed around in a small area and things started melting at 12 volts under load. So...
I'm going for 24 V (2 batteries) into a 3000kW voltage controller, stuffed where the twist-tiller assembly was, and into a 60 pound thrust Striker(12V). I've extended the 10K speed pot and directional switch to the forward control panel with steering using a conventional boat steering system. I'll let you all know if there's magic smoke tomorrow! (I've thrown in oars)

Answer (score 5):

I agree.  Your time has value.  But solutions also have value.  I hope you think better of your *time* than wasting it on dead-end fantasy solutions that aren't going to happen.

The problem with maritime power is that energy requirement is quadratic to speed - that's why boats cruise slower than max speed. So you're talking about a considerable amount of energy and that'll mean bigger motor, bigger battery and bigger controller.  Trolling motors are for trolling.

A lot of people are working on Electric Vehicles for over 30 years, and there's an astounding amount of tech out there designed for vehicle builds and conversions.

Your best bet will be finding an outboard motor that will give you the speed you want, and strip out the gas engine. (needless to say, units with known-bad gas engines are a good choice). Replace it with a right-sized electric motor and controller from the vast catalogs of the electric vehicle suppliers.  I'm sure you won't be the first on the lake to do that.

The best combos these days are dog-simple 3-phase AC induction motors and fairly sophisticated motor controllers.  An AC motor has no moving parts.  By which I mean the spinning rotor is entirely passive, just a hunk of aluminum.  This means if you swamp the motor, it's easy to tear down and clean up - the electrical parts are simple coils, and are potted.  If they're messed up, any competent motor shop knows what to do with it.

The smarts/guts are in the controller.  That, you need to carefully seal in a watertight box.  It may have a water line in/out for cooling, but your outboard motor probably already has a water cooling loop for the old engine.

Then it's just a matter of a big enough battery to provide the range you want.

Comment: That is a great idea! I actually have a small 2-stroke outboard in my shed. I don't know why I didn't think of that! what size of BLDC motor do you think might be a good fit? I have a few deep cycle batteries. I have never wired batteries parallel but I'm sure watching a YouTube video could teach me a thing or two about that.

Comment: @MattJames That project is way, way too big for SE comments... your next step is find the Electric Vehicle enthusiast forums and hobnob with them about the best approach to this... sizing, motor type, etc. Water protection must be at the top of the list.  BLDC motors are limited by the strength of their permanent magnet... vehicle applications seem to favor AC induction motors.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  I was about to suggest a serious edit to your answer, until during the course of writing my suggested improvement I realised why you were correct, so now I'm only suggesting a clarification. Force needed to move through a liquid is quadratic with speed, so power is cubic with speed. As time taken is reciprocal to speed, energy consumed for a given distance is again quadratic. It might be worth mentioning both, as it could be the battery energy or the motor power that would be the killer issue.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica i tore apart the small outboard motor that i have. there is no longer a gas engine on top. I have been doing so research on AC induction motors. Would you be able to run one with 1 or 2 deep cycle batteries? or would i need to jig 120 volts worth of batteries together connect them to the motor. Now disconnect the motor and re-connect it the opposite way, that is, the motor lead that was connected to the + side of the battery, now goes to the - side, and viceversa. NOW disconnect and re-connect as it was the first time? in that case, maybe 36v BLDC motor?

Comment: @MattJames If you use an AC motor, you'll need to use a **motor:controller set** that is reasonably well matched.  You wouldn't use J random induction motor out of a circular saw, because you probably don't want to build a 170-volt battery pack lol or use a more expensive higher  voltage AC controller.   You can also look into R/C model airplane motors; they have some high power AC induction or BLDC motors with appropriate controllers, which of course use a low battery voltage.  It's now time to talk to the electric vehicle forums about sizing...

Comment: Do you know of any good Forums? i have been looking but all of the ones i have been able to find so far are for people whom like DRIVING electric cars, not designing them lol

Comment: @MattJames https://www.google.com/search?q=electric+vehicle+conversion+forums&oq=electric+vehicle+conversion+forums&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5j69i61l2.8735j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the motor there is only so much you can do, since the motor is going to have a power limit over which you risk burning it out.

However you may be able to get enhanced performance in exchange for a shorter lifespan by increasing the battery voltage to some degree.

A solid state voltage booster will probably not be practical, due to the high current/power involved here.

Rather I would look at alternative batteries. You can put 2 lead acid deep cycles in series for 24v, but that will probably be excessive. You can balance that out by adding a PWM motor controller to throttle the motor a bit. This isn't too complicated electrically, but I don't know of a cheap all-in-one module that will do it at this power level.

You could use 3 6V lead acid batteries in series for 18V, which is a more reasonable level of overdrive.

Or.. you could build a 4s or 5s lipo pack (that's  15.2 or 19v). Lipos are great for electric vehicles because they have high power ratings and great capacity for their weight. Unfortunately they're also expensive, and they need to be charged with a special balance charger. You could spec it out, but I suspect a lipo pack with similar range to your old battery will be 3 or 4x more expensive.

Re-winding the motor is an option if you've got a lot of time and patience. I would recommend watching some youtube videos to see if you want to get into that. You can basically tune the motor to draw as much as you want at 12v; but it will not be easy.

These are just some ideas.

Comment: It's one thing to rewind a motor for a different voltage.  But to wind it for different *power* you just need to make the windings bigger.  I don't see a way around that.

Comment: Yeah, he'd still be over-driving it.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you have the minimum a 105 amp-hour rated Marine battery. This can supply 12V*<105A for <1 hr or ~ 1200Wh

An efficient 1 Hp DC motor is equivalent to about 800~850 Watts drawn of electricity and may give you a 1200wh/850W= 1.4 h runtime.  Does that jive with your experience?

So how much power do you need must be done with bigger mot and batteries.

So adding a 2nd 105 Ah battery or two might be too heavy or expensive but would get you home faster.

I had a summer job doing seismic research near Kenora ON Canada in the early 70's and we had  olf Ampex 24 channel Reel tape recorders and vacuum tube amplifiers donated from Texaco for University Earth Sciences and car batteries all around the edge of the boat.  Well it had a gas engine may 40 hp but going home into a stiff wind and all that battery weight, we were lucky to get home at 5 MPH in a few hours with the boat so loaded down and 3 people.

I know a tech who built a DC powered boat using an old Merc engine and installed a surplus X Hp motor. Online you can buy Electronic Speed controllers or ESC for motors so get one bigger than what you think you need and limit the acceleration which always takes more current than rated load (up to 10x).

- matching the prop to the motor speed is critical, so use one for good torque like for water skiing.

Comment: Troll alert. = someone with no value added content -1